# Image hover effects

Tags: html, css

This is the fiddle i have created http://jsfiddle.net/pAQTn/

If you see the way it works now is on hover of the images the image enlarges in size by 20 percent and overlaps into the table.

How can i enlarge the image and at the same time enlarge the dimensions of my table.
Here is my code.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/095/Purple/v4/f3/ac/2f/f3ac2f01-fa54-2dd6-09fc-5cee611d42db/mzl.cakizdof.100x100-75.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="100" height="100">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/095/Purple/v4/f3/ac/2f/f3ac2f01-fa54-2dd6-09fc-5cee611d42db/mzl.cakizdof.100x100-75.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="100" height="100">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/095/Purple/v4/f3/ac/2f/f3ac2f01-fa54-2dd6-09fc-5cee611d42db/mzl.cakizdof.100x100-75.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="100" height="100">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/095/Purple/v4/f3/ac/2f/f3ac2f01-fa54-2dd6-09fc-5cee611d42db/mzl.cakizdof.100x100-75.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="100" height="100">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the CSS

```
img:hover {
    border:1px solid #0000ff;
    width:120%;
    height:120%;
}
```

Comment: Use float instead of tables

Comment: can u be more specific please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used to `%` into `px` as like this

```
img:hover{
     border:1px solid #0000ff;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pAQTn/2/)**

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks. Can believe i did not get that.

Comment: What if you don't know the size in pixels and want to increase the image size?

Comment: Actually i have hard coded the images to 100*100 so i do not think that should be a problem even if the source is bigger than than size

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is convert `%` to `px` and than use `position: absolute;` so that your cells wont move

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pAQTn/4/)

```
img:hover{
    border:1px solid #0000ff;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: What if you don't know the size in pixels and want to increase the image size?

Comment: Im getting confused. DoctorMick i tried your demo. it does not work for me. Im running chrome. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at above, you can't use %.  If you use % it will try to set the height and width to 120% of the container so then obviously can't resize the container otherwise it would then have to resize the image again and that would obviously go on infinitely.

If you wrap the image in another element, i.e. a div, it might do what you're looking for but I haven't got round to trying it.

Edit: the div didn't work!